# How can I capture date information from a rails form?

Tags: ruby, forms, date, capture, ruby-on-rails

I followed a few rails tutorials online, and it seems that to capture a date, I'd use date_select helper. But for some reason or another all the other data is captured in the database (SQLite3) except for the birthday. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code for the form in my view:

```
  <% form_for :user, :url => {:controller=>'users', :action=> "signup_student"} do |f| %>
    <div>
      <%= f.label :last_name, "Last Name" %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :last_name, :size => 40 %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= f.label :birthday, "Birthday" %>
      <%= f.date_select :birthday%>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Any ideas would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: this should worked? check datatype for 'birthday' column it should be date or datetime also please paster your 'signup_student' method

Comment: Hi, I suspect your tutorial is outdated, because I haven't used form_for like that in a really long time. Anyway, your date_select looks okay. You say it is making it into the database, which implies it gets through routes and into your controller method. Can you show the controller method, and any relevant portions of the model (ie anything dealing with birthday, and any attr_accessible or attr_protected)

Comment: Does the `users` table have a `birthday` field? Just asking.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, make sure that your database field type is set to `datetime`. If it isn't, you can change it with:

```
change_column :user, :birthday, :datetime
```

Once you've done that, you can use `datetime_select` instead of `datetime`:

```
<%= f.datetime_select :birthday%>
```